# Laravel not seeing form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

This is my controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->has('order')){
        dd('nice');}
 } else if ($request->has('delete')){
        $fileToDelete = $request->input('delete');
        Image::where('id', $fileToDelete)->delete();
        return redirect('settings/photos');
```

This is my blade file

```
 <form action="{{route("settings.postphotos")}}" name="order" method="post">
        @csrf
        <label for="sort">Order by : </label><select name="sort" form="order">
            <option value="name">Name</option>
            <option value="dateAdded">Date added</option>
        </select><select name="sortBy" form="order">
            <option value="asc">Ascending</option>
            <option value="des">Descending</option>
        </select><input type="submit"  value="Order" class="settings-photos-delete-btn"/>
    </form>
  <form action="{{route("settings.postphotos")}}" method="post" name="delete" class="text-center">
                    @csrf
                    <input type="hidden" name="delete" value="{{$images->id}}" />
                    <input type="submit"  value="Delete" class="settings-photos-delete-btn"/><br/>
                </form>
```

The controller sees the delete form but not the order form please what am i doing wrong

Comment: what result do you get when you push the delete button?

Comment: It performs the operation i want it to, it deletes the file i want it to delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a input named "order" in your order form
create/rename one

```
 <form action="{{route("settings.postphotos")}}" name="order" method="post">
        @csrf
        <label for="sort">Order by : </label><select name="sort" form="order">
            <option value="name">Name</option>
            <option value="dateAdded">Date added</option>
        </select><select name="sortBy" form="order">
            <option value="asc">Ascending</option>
            <option value="des">Descending</option>
        </select><input type="submit" name="order" value="Order" class="settings-photos-delete-btn"/>
    </form>
```

Comment: glad to have helped